# Can't select faces properly on blender 2.80

Tags: vertices, edges, faces, select

i'm using Blender 2.80 (fa9ab7b5a9a5).

In EDIT mode i can select Vertex or Edges just fine, but when trying to select FACE, blender selects some other face except the one i'm hovering my mouse.

It only works fine when enabling Scene Transparency.

This is happening in all Shading modes, with Center On/Off in the Overlays panel, with OpenGL Depth Picking On/Off in the preferences either with my mouse or pen tablet (wacom), with or without Gizmos.

I have loaded Factory Settings.

I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1080Ti with driver 430.86.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I didn´t understand what was going on and i could not solve my problem.

So i made a clean install of Blender 2.80 (cc600de6695a) and the problem is now solved.

Thanks